# React typescript ref return null in conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to use React refs, it works **fine** in static rendering, e.g:

```
<footer ref="ftr"></footer>
```

But, **not** in conditional rendering, e.g:

```
{footer ?
    <footer ref="ftr"></footer>
: null}
```

When I called `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.ftr);`, the first way returned the **element** (fine) but the second returned me **undefined**.

How to do the right way in conditional rendering? Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use string refs as written [in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs):

> We advise against it because string refs have some issues, are
>   considered legacy, and are likely to be removed in one of the future
>   releases

You can do this:

```
let footerElement: HTMLElement | null = null;
...
{footer ?
    <footer ref={ el => footerElement = el }></footer>
: null}
...
if (footerElement != null) {
    ...
}
```